# Delete using ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div in which its data is populated from the backend php. I am using codeigniter here.
The div is something like this

```
if(isset($result))
{
echo '
  <div>
    <div>
     $result->value
    </div>
    <a>Delete</a>
  </div>
';
}
```

The delete is done using ajax. But how do I do a refresh of the div which is not supposed to show anything after the deletion?

Comment: when you'r saying delete div. do you remove a record from the database or are you changing the DOM? none of them shod need a refresh thou

Comment: i will remove a record from the database, but i more concerned with changing the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your `ajax success function`:

```
$(this).closest('div').slideUp().remove();
```

This way visually you would see a slideup and after sliding up this would get removed from the dom and this won't appear again if successfully removed from db.

`Then if you refresh your page you won't see that div again.`

Answer (score 0):

having some kind of class identifier on delete is always a good way for future extensions/modifications.

```
<div>
    <div>
     $result->value
    </div>
    <a class="deleteme">Delete</a>
</div>
```

either case you can use this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteme', function() {
   //your delete stuff 
   if (your delete was successful) {
     $(this).parent().fadeOut(500);
   }
});
```